# How to put an image in an R presentation slide?

Tags: r, shiny

Please I'd like to ask where I am supposed to put the image(.png) for use in a R presentation(.Rpres) slide? I have tried using this code...

```
 ![My test image]("~/Desktop/presentation/coshinyApp/videoButton.png")
```

but the image doesn't show.

Thanks

Comment: it's also accessible from RStudio's menu, but here is a [Rmarkdown cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.org/links/r_markdown_cheat_sheet). See page 2, left column, close to the RStudio icon (+1 @rawr).

Comment: @rawr and Vincent: thanks guys for your reply and help . I have got it to work now. Cheers!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Better solution that works for me best for embedding images . 
Make sure you keep the png/jpg , in the same folder as the presentation for clarity

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
   knitr::include_graphics('./Capture-Output.png')
```
````